# NSnumberFormatter working on simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsnumberformatter

There is a price field in my App. I used NSNumberFormatter and I am storing and retrieving values using core data. It's working fine on the simulator but nothing is showing up on the device.

I am also displaying the local currency value which is working fine on the simulator but not on the device. I used the following code for the currency:

```
NSLocale *theLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *a = [theLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol];
```

Comment: Check whether device Locale and Simulator Locale are same

Comment: No but i changed the locale in simulator and checked and it worked.

Comment: simulator is in US and my phone's locale is India.

Comment: Does the vairiable `theLocale` contains the India locale when running on your device or does it return `nil`? What about `[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];` (even if this returns the current language, according to the preferred language settings, not the current locale according to the region settings that you should use for the currency symbol, it's worth checking if this works or return `nil` too)

Comment: its returning rupee symbol and preferred languages is returning en on the simulator

Comment: but all i can see is a square on the device

Answer (score 1):

For Indian Number System

```
    NSNumberFormatter *frm=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[frm setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    [frm setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_IN"] autorelease]];
[frm setCurrencySymbol:@""];

NSString *formattedAmt=[frm stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:tmpAmt]];
```

**Change LocaleIdentifier to en_US  for Millions**